# What is causing error: "Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame" in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, widget, size, kivymd

I was trying to set up a screen layout made of nested BoxLayouts. Unfortunately, when I try to set up two bottom buttons' size (using size_hint: 0.5,0.5) I get this error:

*[CRITICAL] [Clock] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute.*

However, I get the expected result: [Two bottom buttons are in expected place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/velAw.png), but after a while application crashes.

## .kv file

```
<Window2>:
    name: 'Window2'
    
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            
            MDLabel:
                id: label_id
                text: 'Text'
                
            MDDropDownItem:
                id: drop_item
                text: 'Condition'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                font_size: 32
                on_release: 
                    root.menu.open()

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
        
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Back'
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.5 # this line is causing the problem
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current = 'Window1'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Continue'
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.5 # this line is causing the problem
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current = 'Window3'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

Comment: Could you post the traceback at the point when it eventually crashes?

Comment: Ok, I did some testing and I can describe behavior of warning messages more thoroughly. 

The warning message appears when I start my Application (it's another screen) and spams multiple times per second warning message "[CRITICAL] [Clock] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame" until I reach "Window2" of my layout - then spamming stops. This behavior is happening only when I am trying to set buttons on "Window2" via size_hint property. And however, the application does not crash on this warning message (but spams a lot).

Comment: So it looks like when the buttons were rendered, then everything is okey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved my issue by changing buttons from KivyMD RaisedButtons to standard Kivy Buttons.